# How to save thorn with ansi encoding in PHP?

Tags: php, character-encoding, special-characters, ansi

I have to save a text file with ansi encoding, containing the special character "thorn" or "þ" in PHP. When I simply place the thorn in PHP, it is going to look like "ţ" in the file. I have tried many different ways without luck, and have no idea how I could save the thorn correctly. Could you please give me some advice? Thank you.

after iconv('UTF-8', 'Windows-1252', $this->filedata); (mb_convert_encoding() makes no difference either)

þ ==> ţ

utf8_encode("þ") ==> Ăľ

I'm using Netbeans 15 for coding and notepad++ 8.4.8 for checking the results

Something is very strange: I have the PHP generated ANSI Text file, where the thorn looks like ţ and when I copy / paste it to another ANSI text file created with Notepad++, it is inserted simply as a t. When I convert thorn with Notepad++, it's going to be a ?. Maybe a bug in Np++?

Comment: How did you load the file? Using `notepad`?

Comment: I'm using Notepad++

Comment: Did you use an IDE to edit the PHP file, or also notepad++?

Comment: I'm using Netbeans 15 for coding

Comment: In Notepad++, for the output file, do you see `ISO 8859-2` or `ANSI` in the bottom right? If so, try using the menu: `Encoding > Character sets > Western European > ISO 8859-1`

Comment: I see ANSI. After Encoding > Character sets > Western European > ISO 8859-1 it looks correct, but it's not ANSI anymore and the software I have to feed with this text file accepts ANSI only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your php file is in utf8, then the following saves the "þ" in Windows-1252 encoding:

```
$text = iconv('UTF-8', 'Windows-1252', 'þ');
file_put_contents('./output.txt', $text);
```

Your `þ` will be saved as `0xFE` (numeric value: 254). 
Windows-1252 is the same as ISO-8859-1 except for 0x80 to 0x9F.

If you can check hex dump, you can verify that `FE` is there (it only takes one byte).

---

However, in Windows, a text file in the so-called "ANSI" (*non-Unicode*) is loaded differently depending on your system locale:

- If the Windows system locale is Romanian (Romania), an "ANSI" text file is loaded like ISO-8859-2, so the `0xFE` byte is loaded as `ţ` (not thorn, but rather "t with a cedilla").
  If you look at [ISO-8859-2 code page layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-2#Code_page_layout), there is no "thorn" letter. 
  Basically, the **pre-Unicode** encoding for *Romanian* (or another similar language) **does not support the þ character**.
- If the Windows system locale is English (United States), an "ANSI" text file is loaded like ISO-8859-1, so that you can see `þ` even in a non-Unicode program. But then it does not support `ţ`. In [ISO-8859-1 code page layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Code_page_layout), you see that `þ` is placed exactly where you expect `ţ` in ISO-8859-2.

Other system locales may interpret `0xFE` differently depending on which **pre-Unicode** encoding suited their language.

To change locale (Windows 11):
From `Settings`, find `Time & language > Language & region > Administrative language settings`.
Then click on the `Administrative` tab. Then you should see "Current language for non-Unicode programs". Then choose "Change system locale..." (you need administrative privilege for this).

(Note that the locale may be different from the Windows display language).

---

Regarding unsupported characters, text editors must find a way to get rid of them (for example, by replacing them with actually supported characters), otherwise they can't exactly save the results (because there is no correct *byte representation* for your original data in *the current encoding*).

Sometimes an unsupported character is simply replaced with `?`, sometimes it's another similar letter (like you see how `ţ` was replaced with `t`). In any case, you can't save/load the letter `þ` properly *unless the encoding supports that character*. Similarly for `ţ`.

Notepad++ shows (bottom right) which encoding it is currently using. If you see "ANSI" (and your OS is Windows), then the actual scheme depends on the system locale.

Comment: I thought it was german, but turned out it was something different, no clue why, I have never changed it. I was changing it to german, and it looks fine. Thank you!

Comment: @user2511599 Yes, the old Windows encoding for German does support `þ`. Maybe some software you ran changed the locale (without telling you), or maybe the computer was bought in another country, just that the display language was changed to German?

Comment: I was buying the component myself here in Germany, installed german Windows, so... it could be rather the first option. But changing it without telling...?! That's also funny. :)

Comment: @user2511599 Well, malware may change your system settings without telling you.

Answer (score 0):

[mb_detect_encoding()](https://www.plumislandmedia.net/wordpress/translating-phps-imap-extension-in-wordpress/)  makes a guess: it is not guaranteed to generate the correct results. You're better off if you know the character encoding of your input file via other means.

If your file already contains the codepoint (===character) for `þ` it probably is already coded in windows-1252 or iso-8859-1, and doesn't need conversion.

This kind of work can be confusing because the output rendering of any text depends on system or application locale settings. A file can be rendered assuming it has a different character set than the one it was encoded with.  Use a hex-dump program to examine the file. Or standardize your text files on utf-8 if possible.

You haven't given us enough information to help you further.

Comment: When you create a normal string in PHP it is going to be UTF-8 I think. What information are you missing? I'll do my best to give the information you need if I can.